# Angular2: getting service's property value before call a method

Tags: rxjs

I have implemented `FireDatabaseService` as `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in my app. It of course works with DI. In this service I need Firebase UID from another service, but this UID is being fetched with subscription. Because of this methods that need UID are called before this UID is available. I have no idea how to get UID before `getUserGroup()` is called. Here is my service:

```
...
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FireDatabaseService {
  uid: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private readonly authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(
      (state: firebase.User) => this.uid = state.uid
    );
  }

  getUserGroup(): Observable<string> {
    return this.db
      .object(`users/${this.uid}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((userData: any) => userData?.group as string));
  ...
  }
```

Calling `fireDatabaseService.getUserGroup()` goes with `uid = ''`. Is there any possibility to fix it? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little unclear to me what your requirements are. The easiest way to accomplish what I think you are asking would be the following:

```
...
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FireDatabaseService {
  constructor(
    private readonly db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private readonly authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  getUserGroup(): Observable<string> {
    return this.authService
               .authState
               .pipe(
                   switchMap((state: firebase.User) => 
                       this.db
                           .object(`users/${state.uid}`)
                           .valueChanges()
                   ),
                   map((userData: any) => userData?.group as string)
               );
  ...
  }
```

Everytime `getUserGroup` is called, there would be another call to the authService. That might be undesireable, but that could be mitigated through the use of `shareReplay(1)` or through another strategy depending on the functionality you are expecting.

Comment: Nice work :), I have a question why did you choose the switchMap operator in favor of the MergMap operator?

Comment: @RebaiAhmed The difference between the two operators is explained [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap#why-use-mergemap).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not subscribe at all in your service, but rather define your `uid` and `userGroup` as observables.  The `userGroup$` can be defined from the `uid$` observable:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FireDatabaseService {
  uid$ = this.authService.authState.pipe(
    map(state => state.uid)
  );

  userGroup$ = this.uid$.pipe(
    switchMap(uid => this.db.object(`users/${uid}`).valueChanges())
    map(userData => userData?.group as string)
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private readonly authService: AuthService
  ) { }
}
```

Observables are lazy, so it is not necessary to wrap them as functions.  They don't emit a value until `.subscribe()` is called on them.

Comment: userGroup$ still require defined uid$, and uid$ is defined after userGroup$ call :(

Comment: In the above code, the calls aren't actually being made, they are only being defined.  So, when `userGroup$.subscribe()` is called, the `uid$` subscription will happen first, so the `switchMap` inside `userGroup$` will get the current `uid`.  Give it a try :-)

Comment: well I gave, i just repeat what my console says :D

Comment: 2nd solution helped, I think it's enough. but thanks anyway!